# Can't install Nuget or other extension to VS2012 on Win8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When I try to install any extension for visual studio ultimate 2012 on my new installation of Winodws 8 I get this exception :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.GetScopePaths(String
>   applicationPath, String suffixOrName, String vsVersion, Boolean
>   isLogged, Boolean isForIsolatedApplication)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.ExternalSettingsManager.CreateForApplication(String
>   applicationPath)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManager(SupportedVSSKU sku)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.GetExtensionManagerForApplicableSKU(SupportedVSSKU
>   supportedSKU, IInstallableExtension installableExtension, List`1
>   applicableSKUs)    at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

I tryed to repair VS, did not work, and also try to uninstall/install and got the same problem. Anybody as an idea?

Comment: did you try running as admin? Where is VS installed? Are you [redirecting your documents folder to a network share](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/240739)?

Comment: Yes I try to run as admin and it does not change anything. I got it working on my PC at work but not at home. It's all on c drive.

Comment: not quite sure if it's an answer but if I add full control to security tab direct on my c: the install works...

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped by this until I realized that I had somehow deleted my My Documents directory. Recreating `C:\Users\<username>\Documents` allowed it to install.

Others have reported [the same bug when My Documents has been remapped to a different location](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/700). The workaround is to map it back to the standard location, install the `vsix`, and reestore your mapping.

If all else fails, you can manually unpack the extension:

- In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Extensions and Updates, and install a working extension from the online repository (I used "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Feedback Tool"). For some reason, this is needed to get new extensions you manually unpack to show up in VS.
- Close Visual Studio.
- Unpack the `.vsix` file as a subdirectory of the Visual Studio extensions directory `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11\Extensions\`, alongside the extension you installed (I used 7-zip).
- Re-open Visual Studio. Under Extensions and Updates, the new extension showed up but was marked disabled. Enable it and restart VS.